# Creating custom polymer element

Tags: polymer-cli

I am trying to create a new template such that if I do this:

```
polymer init <custom-element>
```

I get a new project created in the development system.

Is there any documentation on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom option in `polymer init` command, we have to build a new Yeoman generator. [Here](http://yeoman.io/authoring/) is a guide on how to do that.

The only condition that generator should satisfy so that it is recognized by [polymer cli](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) is:

- The generator should be named `generator-polymer-init` followed by the name that we use in `polymer init` command.

For example, let us say we want `polymer init custom-build` option, we need to create a Yeoman generator with name `generator-polymer-init-custom-build`. In fact, polymer developers have created a generator with the same name that we can take a look: [generator-polymer-init-custom-build](https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build)